How do I get around this issue?
While I was working, I noticed that the images we're supposed to tag on our company e-mails are all inconsistent and low resolution.
When I told my boss, he agreed it would be good to fix that issue and tasked me to do it.
However, the company logo changed some months ago and the new company logo has different sizes on diferent e-mails.
After looking for a while, I stumbled upon the company's LinkedIn page and noticed I could use that as a reference.
Since I'm not a professional coder, I don't think I did the "right thing" to get the image.
All I did was using F12 to get to this link:
https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/v2/D4D03AQFm30GcaRYlSw/profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200/profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200/0/1681152976155?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=f3gM-z9-rPlA8TFS3gHgKhJWt3bEwIUZVkMtin01c-4
Then I edited the link a bit and got some error messages that looked like this:
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "example.link" on this server.
Reference #18.e72a1102.1726747228.26b479cf

https://errors.edgesuite.net/18.e72a1102.1726747228.26b479cf

Until I got this link:
https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/v2/D4D03AQFm30GcaRYlSw/
And instead of getting the image or the same error message, I got this message:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>403 - Forbidden</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>403 - Forbidden</h1>
    </body>
</html>

Then, after trying something different, the same error message appeared, replacing the other one:
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://media.licdn.com/dms/image/v2/D4D03AQFm30GcaRYlSw/" on this server.
Reference #18.e72a1102.1726747273.26b724e2

https://errors.edgesuite.net/18.e72a1102.1726747273.26b724e2

Why did this happen and what am I supposed to do in order to get the image?
